# AWS ECR - Apply IAM policy that applies to all repositories and not individually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I am trying to set cross account access to ECR repositories.
The only way I get to make it work is setting permission individually for each repository.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:DeleteRepository",
        "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
        "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::my-other-cross-account:root"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "new statement"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2008-10-17"
}
```

But I have many repositories and I would like to do it just once that apply for all repositories.
I also have set iam global roles to be assumed from other accout but it does not work and the only way to make it work is individually settting for each repository.

Thanks

Comment: as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html the code you are using looks okay at a glance. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Here's a related AWS roadmap item https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/799 As currently defined, the default would only take effect at creation time though